# Storing user preferences in Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm wondering how Web Sites often add new features and new preferences without making a mess of the database.

I thought of storing these in a preferences table with a many to many relationship and a key value pair.

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: In the end, "User Preferences" is just a subsection of "Data" that a web application will need to store. As such, I don't think there is one correct way to answer this question. You might as well ask "How do web sites typically store their data", which of course has a number of answers (as numerous as there are database types and strategies to use those databases, and maybe even client-side storage in some cases). Can you make your question more specific? Is there a specific problem you are having?

Comment: In addition to @MarkHildreth comment - any question with "better"/"best" is pretty much unanswerable. You need to define what "better" is for you so suggestions can be made for changes toward *your* "better" goal.

Comment: Why not store them on the users PC w/ cookies, then parse them on the session load. You could less sensitive settings there.

Comment: @Anon very bad idea to store them on cookies. The cookie if follow you on every page call, the size is limited, can be change by hand, not safe etc...

Comment: @Aristos notice I said 'Less Sensitive' settings. I was thinking things like page color, font, etc...He never specified what kind of settings. Why would cookies be a bad idea for settings like those?

Comment: @Aristos Yea I get that, but once  your cookie has been parsed (Start of session), then you don't need to touch it again. That would only be 1 call.  
I do see the limitation, but i dont think its a "Very bad idea", that what they were made for.

Comment: @Aristos thanks for the discussion. Apparently we have different views on the topic. Sorry OP about the hijack.

Comment: @Anon At least take some time and read that http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use the asp.net User Profile Properties that comes together with the login module of the asp.net

Read about and see some examples right on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing a portion of your data in a NoSQL database or in a NoSQL style data structure--just like you're saying, key/value pairs.

My personal preference is to store the primary and foreign keys and minimal identification data in a normalized data structure and store other attributes in a NoSQL database or data structure.  That way the other attributes can be added and removed easily and can even be different from one record to another.